# Angular 2 Resolve - Local Variable scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular etc, and I have been playing around with resolve. However, when I want to pass a local boolean I get undefined? i'm trying to understand why. This below is my guard, my service just calls an api and it is passing. I want to pass a boolean to the component that the resolve is attached to, in order to display an error or not.

```
resolve(): boolean {
    let passed: boolean;
    let uid: string = window['appdata'].uid;
    let tbt: string = window['appdata'].tbt
    let lang: string = window['appdata'].apiUserLanguage;

    if(uid != null || undefined && tbt != null && undefined){
        console.log('Uid is: ' + uid + ' tbt is: ' + tbt);
        this.validateEmailService.emailCheck(uid, tbt, lang).subscribe( 
            data => {
                passed = true;
            },
            err => {
                passed = false;
            }
        );
    }
    console.log('Passed is: ' + passed);
    return passed;
}
```

}

Comment: Something to point out from your condition: undefined is falsy. 
So in your condition: uid != null || undefined && tbt != null && undefined
this part never gets evaluated: (undefined && tbt != null && undefined).

That should be part of your issue.

Comment: You're setting the value for passed asynchronously, but you're logging the value synchronously. In other words, `console.log('Passed is: ' + passed);` happens before `this.validateEmailService.emailCheck` is completed.

Comment: Thank you Baruch, For my particular use case i wonder if it would be better to use a promise instead of an observable and then use .then()

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the boolean will be returned ,but you can show it after subscribing the observable returned by the service, because `subscribe` is an asynchrounous method. try to log it into `subscribe` like this & its value will be shown :)

```
resolve(): boolean {
let passed: boolean;
let uid: string = window['appdata'].uid;
let tbt: string = window['appdata'].tbt
let lang: string = window['appdata'].apiUserLanguage;

if(uid != null || undefined && tbt != null && undefined){
    console.log('Uid is: ' + uid + ' tbt is: ' + tbt);
    this.validateEmailService.emailCheck(uid, tbt, lang).subscribe( 
        data => {
            passed = true;
            console.log('Passed is: ' + passed);// Passed is: true
        },
        err => {
            passed = false;
            console.log('Passed is: ' + passed);// Passed is: false
        }
    );
}

return passed;
```

}